# Почему TypesScript пропускает ошибку на этапе присвоения результата парсинга json?

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Пример кода:

```
type MyType  = {
    id:number,
    page:number,

}
const j = `{"id": "1", "page": "2"}`
const a:MyType = JSON.parse(j) 

console.log(typeof a.id, parseInt(a.id,10), a.id)
```

В результате парсинга json строки, все числа являются `string`, но при этом переменной `a` присвоен тип у которого `id` указан как `number`. Почему ts не ругается на этой строке, а выдает ошибку когда я хочу выполнить `parseInt(a.id,10)`

[Код](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta&ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5pQLxQN4FgBQU9QEsATALgDsBXAWwCMIAnAGh3yjAEMBzCc6upnDgC%20OAMYB7MgGdgUAFaooAA3QAiYqpJRVARlWNtHbpu0AmVUKVjJMqOxJxEkRQCkAygHkAcgDoO9KQgACjkASihBbAlpcQAbCB9Y8U4g0EhxADM7H2IDf0CASTJgIPYcokYdAAZQgzLiUJwgA)

Comment: TypeScript не способен определить что может вернуть `JSON.parse` и возвращает
`:any`, [который](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), в свою очередь, может быть присвоен любому типу.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите безопасное решение, то вам нужна собственная функция, которая бы проверяла JSON и выводила тип ( `typescript` из коробки так не умеет )

```
type MyType = {
    id: number,
    page: number,

}
const j1 = `{ "id": "1", "page": "2" }`;
const j2 = `{ "id": 1, "page": 2 }`;

// Эта функция говорит typescript, что в случае true переданный аргумент имеет тип MyType.
const isMyType = (json: any): json is MyType => {
    const values = Object.values(json);
    for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (typeof values[i] !== 'number') {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

const a = JSON.parse(j1);
const b = JSON.parse(j2);

if (isMyType(a)) {
    console.log(a); // не выведется.
}

if (isMyType(b)) {
    console.log(b); // выведется и тип будет равен MyType.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

В json строке цифры указаны как строка, уберите кавычки, тогда  они станут числами

```js
const j = `{"id": 1, "page": 2}`
```